# Woocommerce rest api add booking products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

Is there anyway to add booking products in woocommerce rest api? I am trying to create a new booking product using woocommerce rest api and it doesn't work for booking but for product type like variable, simple, external, group there are working fine.

Comment: Hey @AyDee did you ever come to a solution?